# Pandas to_mardown() highlight row

Tags: python, pandas, jira, tabulate

Is it possible to change the text color for a  specific row when using `df.to_markdown()`?

I have attempted using `df.style.apply([styles]).to_markdown()` but does does not work since it converts the df into an styler object.

code:

```
print(labels_data.to_markdown(headers= df.columns, tablefmt="jira",  showindex=True))
```

df styled code:

```
def row_name(x):
    for i in x:
        if x.name=='Control':

            return ['background: yellow']
        else:
            return ''
labels_data = count_labels(labels).sort_values('% meets', ascending=False)
labels_data.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' 
                                  if (x.name == 'control')
                                  else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

My use case is printing a markdown to copy paste a table (with styles) in jira.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use html? Html is valid inline within markdown, but there isn't a standard way of marking rows within a markdown table (not that markdown is a much of standard, in practice, anyway).